# Converting GPS Degree to GPS Decimal

Tags: mysql, converters, latitude-longitude

I am working on converting Latitude Degrees to Latitude Decimal, I have been able to accomplish this to an extent.  The problem I am running into, is that everyday my database gets updated with new GPS Degree format and when my query runs it pulls what has already been converted and does the mathematical equation on them as well.  When it updates it makes the GPS Decimal that I already had wrong.  Here is what I have so far.  To pull to a temporary table.

```
`UPDATE
        ztestgps
INNER JOIN
        account on account.accountnumber = ztestgps.Account Number
SET
        ztestgps.Latitude = account.latitude,
        ztestgps.Longitude = account.Longitude`
```

This pulls all of the data I need to do the math on.  Then I run the Math with

```
`UPDATE
        ztestgps
SET
        ztestgps.LatMinutes = SUBSTRING(ztestgps.Latitude,-7,2),
        ztestgps.LatSeconds = SUBSTRING(ztestgps.latitude,-5,5),
        ztestgps.LatDecimal = ztestgps.LatDegree + (ztestgps.LatMinutes/60) + (ztestgps.LatSeconds/3600),
        ztestgps.LongDegree = LEFT(ztestgps.Longitude,2),
        ztestgps.LongMinutes = SUBSTRING(ztestgps.Longitude,-7,2),
        ztestgps.LongSeconds = SUBSTRING(ztestgps.Longitude,-5,5),
        ztestgps.LongDecimal = ztestgps.LongDegree + (ztestgps.LongMinutes/60) + (ztestgps.LongSeconds/3600)`
```

I then have one last query that updates the original file `account.latitude` and `account.longitude`.  I haven't been able to find a way for it to ignore what is already in decimal format, and only convert what is in degree format.

Comment: adding a `processed` flag would be the easiest way, not knowing what the exact format is. If tis a normal format the presence of a `'` could be used ?

Comment: It is best to store numbers as numbers, not pieces of numbers.  If you need to display deg/min/sec, then compute as you SELECT.

Comment: @RickJames there is no suitable type for degree/minute/second. What would you suggest? And I don't think it's a "number" - it's a composite type that consists of 3 separate integers.

Comment: @exussum, the flag worked perfectly, I had to write it to remove the flag when the data is pulled, but that would be expected..

Comment: Convert as you insert the data.